# Self в классе и интерфейсе

Tags: delphi, интерфейс, com

Подскажите пожалуйста на что реально указывает встроенная переменная Self в методах, которые вызываются через класс и через интерфейс.
Я заметил, что в этих случаях переменная Self имеет разное значение.

Comment: Это просто указатель на адрес в памяти, где лежит объект.

Comment: Это понятно. Но значение этого адреса разные, если метод вызывается через указатель на переменную этого класса и если метод вызывается через интерфейс.
Поэтому хочется понять внутреннюю структуру - на что физически в этих случаях указывает переменная Self.

Comment: Покажите код, как именно вы вызываете метод через указатель и интерфейс.